# How to fix memory leaking problem with ECMAScripts in SVG animation rotation?

Tags: javascript, svg, memory-leaks

I am trying to make SVG rotation animation and basically get it work based on some instructions online. The problem is, when I load the SVG file into Chrome, with time, the rotation animation effect seems becoming worse and worse. I checked from Chrome Task Manager, and found the tab memory keeping increasing continuously to hundreads of Megabytes. Looks like some memory leaking caused this problem? The SVG file is very simple, just to swing a rect repeatedly. Code attached. Please help point out how to fix this problem.

The code is kind of straightforward and is working. Checked online but rarely found topics on the SVG ECMAScripts caused memory leaking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   onload="Start(evt)"     
   width="200"
   height="200">
   <script type="text/ecmascript">     
   <![CDATA[

    var time = 0;
    var delta_time = 25;
    var max_time = 1000;
    var dir = 1;

    var the_rect;

    function Start(evt) {     

      the_rect = evt.target.ownerDocument.getElementById("BlueRect");     
      Oscillate();
    }

    function Oscillate() {

      time = time + dir * delta_time;
      if (time >  max_time)  dir = -1;
      if (time < -max_time)  dir =  1;

        var the_rect_ani = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","animateTransform");
        the_rect_ani.setAttributeNS(null,"id","the_rect_Ani");
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("attributeName", "transform");
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("attributeType", "xml");
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("type", "rotate" );
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("from", "0"+" "+100+" "+100);
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("to", 360*(dir)+" "+100+" "+100);
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("begin", "0s");
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("dur", "2s");
        the_rect_ani.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite"); 
        the_rect.appendChild(the_rect_ani);

      // Repeat
      setTimeout("Oscillate()", delta_time)
    }

    window.Oscillate = Oscillate

   ]]>
  </script>     
  <a xlink:href="http://www.w3.org/"
     style="fill-opacity:0.75">
    <rect
     id="BlueRect"
     width="90"
     height="90"
     x="30"
     y="30"
     style="fill:#0000ff;stroke:#000000"
     onmouseover="setAttribute('fill-opacity','1.0')"
     onmouseout="setAttribute('fill-opacity','0.75')">
      <desc
       id="desc3364">A clickable square to test simple JavaScript.</desc>
      <title
       id="title3362">Click square to go to http://www.w3.org.</title>
    </rect>
  </a>
</svg>
```

I expect this simple SVG animation running smoothly, consistently with time, while not consuming continuously increased memory.

Comment: There's no leak. Every Oscillate call you add more elements to the DOM that you never remove. You can do the whole thing in SMIL in markup without any javascript at all and then the memory won't increase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually before I use ECMAScripts to achieve this, I was using SMIL. But I can only make it rotate to one direction(e.g., clockwise). Could you please give me some further hint on how to make it rotate clockwise then counter-clockwise with SMIL?

Comment: I just got it resolved. Found this pendulum example: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Animated_pendulum.svg. Indeed now it solves the memory-keep-increasing problem and the performance is much better. Thank you, Robert!